# Object mapper and Jackson Tester

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

What is the difference between object mapper and Jackson tester. According to my knowledge object mapper maps POJO to JSON and vice versa whereas Jackson tester does the same during assertj while writing unit tests of rest controllers.

But I want to know their difference in more detail

Comment: Tester is for tests and mapper for actual usage?

Comment: In test also if you want to do mapping then object mapper is also used along with Jackson Tester